# Whats the most efficient way to split and analyze a line of data points in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I have come at an impasse in my project, I am trying to figure out how to do this but when I come to a new solution it seems more problematic than I thought it would be. I'd appreciate some help in making this efficient:

- I have a USB device that outputs the following every 1/3 of a second:

  ```
  00.000  00.000  00.000  00.000  00.000  00.000  00.000  00.000(Char 13)(Char 10)
  ```

They are temperature values of 9 different channels (they are not zeroes) with a Char 13 and Char 10 (ASCII) at the end. Every value is split by 2 spaces.

I want to do the following:

- Read every 1/3 second
- Split the string using the 2 spaces (variable `SPLIT = " +"`)
- store each reading into a `chx[]` array
- make a new array `time[]` that increments in 1/3 second increments
- rinse repeat.

So by the end of the process I want to have 9 `Channel[]` arrays with x values each and an additional 10th `Time[]` array with x values as well.

This loop needs to keep running until one of the 9 channels is above certain temperature. Then I will analyze the data of each channel and see how long (time) it took for it to ramp up to that temperature (basically checking response time).

Here are my main problems that I am finding:

- I want to do this inside an if loop, however I can't seem to think of a way to state this, it would be something along the lines of:

  ```
  if( /* HOW DO I CONVERT ALL 9 VALUES TO DOUBLES TO CHECK? */ <= finalTemp)
  {
  }
  ```
- Is my reasoning efficient? (an array for each channel and an array for time?)
  if so, I think I'd do a for loop to split, something like this:

  ```
  String[] fullReadings = readData().split(SPLIT);  
  Double[] channel0 = null;  
  Double[] channel1 = null;  
  Double[] channel2 = null;  
  Double[] channel3 = null;  
  Double[] channel4 = null;  
  Double[] channel5 = null;  
  Double[] channel6 = null;  
  Double[] channel7 = null;  
  Double[] time = null;  

  for (int i=0; i<8 ; i++){
  fullReadings = readData().split(SPLIT);

  /* DO I JUST SAY */ channeli = Double.parseDouble(fullReadings[i]); //??

  }
  ```

I appreciate your help and I hope I'm being clear.

**EDIT**
Thank you for the help so far
as of now I have added the class that @James_D suggested, I'm trying his method and I have the following code for the scanner as I could not declare it verbatim like he suggested:

```
try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(input);
                    TemperatureParser parser = new TemperatureParser();
                    inputScanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");
                    do
                    {
                        reading = parser.parse(inputScanner.next());
                        System.out.println(reading);
                        readings.add(reading);
                    } while (testProgress == true);
                    inputScanner.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
                {
                statusLabel.setText("Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
                System.out.println("Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
                }
    }
```

Outside of the method are these declarations:

```
public List<TemperatureReading> readings = new ArrayList<>();
public TemperatureReading reading;
```

Since I dont have the temperature thingy (physically) I just added a start/stop button (boolean testProgress)

Also, have the following code which outputs a blank array?

```
    @FXML
    private void doStopTest(ActionEvent event) {
        setTestInProgress(false);
        writeData(BURSTOFF);
        System.out.println("Stop Button pressed!");
        textLog.appendText("Test stopped by user! \n");
        System.out.println(readings);
        statusLabel.setText("Stopped by User!");
}
```

**NEW EDIT**

Thank you James_D for all your help so far, I really appreciate it. Here is my eventlistener code, since so far it's been working consistently I decided to merge it with some of the code you suggested: Basically, if there is a test in progress it logs, if theres no test in progress it just outputs into a log textfield

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {          
        if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
        {
            if (testProgress == false)
            {
            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                    fullLine = reader.readLine();

                    //System.out.println(fullLine);
                    textLog.appendText(fullLine + "\n");
                    output.flush();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                statusLabel.setText("@serialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
                System.out.println("@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");

            }
            }
            else 
            {
                try
                {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    TemperatureParser parser = new TemperatureParser();
                    reading = parser.parse(reader.readLine());
                    readings.add(reading);
                    fullLine = reader.readLine();
                    textLog.appendText(fullLine + "\n");
                    output.flush();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                statusLabel.setText("@serialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
                System.out.println("@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");

                }

            }
        }


}
```

When I click the stop button (later this will be automatic once the MAX temperature is reached) I have the following code:

```
private void doStopTest(ActionEvent event) {
    writeData(BURSTOFF);
    System.out.println("Stop Button pressed!");
    textLog.appendText("Test stopped by user! \n");
    System.out.println(readings);
    statusLabel.setText("Stopped by User!");
    setTestInProgress(false);

    for (int t = 0; t < readings.size(); t++)
    {
        System.out.println("Time: " + readings.get(t).getTimestamp() + " CH1: " + readings.get(t).getValue(0) + " CH2: " + readings.get(t).getValue(1) + " CH3: " + readings.get(t).getValue(2) + " CH4: " + readings.get(t).getValue(3) + " CH5: " + readings.get(t).getValue(4) + " CH6: " + readings.get(t).getValue(5) + " CH7: " + readings.get(t).getValue(6) + " CH8: " + readings.get(t).getValue(7) + " CH9: " + readings.get(t).getValue(8));
    }
}
```

which when I run the program I get the following output:

```
testProgress is True
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
    at at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController.serialEvent(FXMLDocumentController.java:583)
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort.sendEvent(RXTXPort.java:772)
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort$MonitorThread.run(RXTXPort.java:1641)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
Stop Button pressed!
[at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@44c159a9, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@6fed877b, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@2529a9d6, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@efba5c8, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@4039a9af, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@43ec288c, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@2b635e3e, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@78e57b7f, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@751cc11d, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@57962f7a, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@66b51918, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@3558b832, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@26df83ad, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@40d485f3, at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureReading@ee72928]
testProgress is False
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:19.118 CH1: 24.024 CH2: 23.961 CH3: 23.889 CH4: 24.163 CH5: 24.085 CH6: 24.107 CH7: 24.017 CH8: 24.042 CH9: 24.473
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:19.428 CH1: 24.044 CH2: 23.989 CH3: 23.916 CH4: 24.188 CH5: 24.112 CH6: 24.144 CH7: 24.05 CH8: 24.07 CH9: 24.476
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:19.764 CH1: 24.063 CH2: 24.016 CH3: 23.942 CH4: 24.214 CH5: 24.138 CH6: 24.179 CH7: 24.082 CH8: 24.097 CH9: 24.479
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:20.099 CH1: 24.083 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.969 CH4: 24.24 CH5: 24.164 CH6: 24.215 CH7: 24.114 CH8: 24.123 CH9: 24.482
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:20.418 CH1: 24.102 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.24 CH5: 24.191 CH6: 24.215 CH7: 24.114 CH8: 24.151 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:20.753 CH1: 24.102 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.24 CH5: 24.191 CH6: 24.215 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.151 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:21.088 CH1: 24.102 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.241 CH5: 24.191 CH6: 24.215 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.151 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:21.408 CH1: 24.103 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.241 CH5: 24.191 CH6: 24.215 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.151 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:21.743 CH1: 24.103 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.242 CH5: 24.191 CH6: 24.215 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.152 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:22.062 CH1: 24.103 CH2: 24.044 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.242 CH5: 24.192 CH6: 24.216 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.152 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:22.398 CH1: 24.103 CH2: 24.044 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.243 CH5: 24.192 CH6: 24.216 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.152 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:22.733 CH1: 24.104 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.243 CH5: 24.193 CH6: 24.216 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.152 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:23.052 CH1: 24.104 CH2: 24.044 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.244 CH5: 24.193 CH6: 24.216 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.152 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:23.387 CH1: 24.103 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.996 CH4: 24.244 CH5: 24.193 CH6: 24.216 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.152 CH9: 24.485
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:23.723 CH1: 24.103 CH2: 24.043 CH3: 23.995 CH4: 24.244 CH5: 24.193 CH6: 24.216 CH7: 24.113 CH8: 24.152 CH9: 24.485
```

So you can see that it does log some of the data, and displays it accurately (or so it seems), the first line (testprogress is true) is output when I click the "start test" button and it's the boolean flag to keep logging per the code above. when I click the stop button you get the stop button pressed log and the testprogress is false line which disables the output.

Comment: Probably start with a more appropriate data structure, e.g. a `List<List<Double>>` to store the data from all "channels". (Or, better still, create one or more custom classes. E.g. you could have a `Channel` class, containing a `List<Double>`, and then a `List<Channel>`. Or you could have a `Reading` class that has a timestamp and a `List<Double>` or `double[]` (one value for each channel).

Comment: Hi James, thank you for the comment. I am not too familiar with Lists, from what I've read they're basically dynamic-size arrays? 
Additionally, I can store objects in them so you are suggesting making an List of arrays? 
The list would contain 10 objects: (9 channels + 1 timer) and then how do I access sub-index? (like the 4th element on the 4th object?)

Comment: More or less. Lists are pretty fundamental: any tutorial worth reading will have a large section on lists (and other parts of the collections API). You need a list at some point, because you don't know in advance how many readings you will get (on each channel), which makes it difficult (at least) to use an array (since you need to declare the size of an array before you can use it).

Comment: I think this is way too advanced for you, given what you have said in your comments. I do get the idea that attempting something challenging helps you to learn fast - it at least shows you quickly all the different things you need to learn - but it makes for a really poor question on this forum. At the very most, you should break this down into small pieces and restrict any questions you post to a single piece. Once that is answered, post a new question if you are stuck on a different piece. Else the Q/A will be useless to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Break your program into functions.

```
double[] extractSample(String sampleRow);

double maxTemperature(double[] sample);
```

Depending on exactly what you're analyzing, you could choose to capture a sequence of samples, like `list.add(sample)`, or you might capture the start time in the beginning and just subtract the current time from the start time to get ramp-up time.

Answer (score 0):

> This loop needs to keep running until one of the 9 channels is above certain temperature.

An algorithmic approach, given what I understood from the question.
Note: not checked for syntax and there are many assumptions made, e.g. `readData()` blocks for exactly `1/3` seconds, which may not be true. Hence, care needed with timestamps. Perhaps using `System.nanoTime()` is preferred. However, the following answer is well-matched to the semantics of the question.

```
final double finalTemp = ...;

// 9 channels
double[] channels = new double[9];

long tick = 0;

boolean done = false;

// assume that final temp will be reached
while (!done) {

    // disregarding the Char(13), Char(10), so fullReadings contains temp in String format
    String[] fullReadings = readData().split(SPLIT); 

    // assume fullReadings.length == 9
    for (int i = 0; i < fullReadings.length; i++) {

        // assume the value can be parsed with no errors
        double temp = Double.parseDouble(reading);

        channels[i] = temp;

        if (temp >= finalTemp) {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    tick++;
}

System.out.printf("Time took: %.3f seconds\n", tick / 3.0);

for (int i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Channel %d has temp: %.3f\n", i, channels[i]);
}
```

Comment: So, on this example the time is retrieved by multiplying tick by .3 ?
also, how are you "logging" the temperature? from what I understand in this you are just over-writing the data until it satisfies the greater than finaltemp?

Answer (score 0):

As always, your code gets much simpler if you start by defining some appropriate class(es) to represent the data in the application.

For example, I would probably start with a class that represents the set of values for all channels at one time point:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime ;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream ;

public class TemperatureReading {

    private final double[] values ;

    private final LocalDateTime timestamp ;

    public TemperatureReading(LocalDateTime timestamp, double... values) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp ;
        this.values = new double[values.length];
        System.arraycopy(values, 0, this.values, 0, values.length);
    }

    public TemperatureReading(double... values) {
        this(LocalDateTime.now(), values);
    }

    public double getValue(int channel) {
        return values[channel];
    }

    public int getNumberOfChannels() {
        return values.length ;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp ;
    }

    public boolean noneExceed(double max) {
        return DoubleStream.of(values)
            .allMatch(v -> v <= max)
    }

}
```

Now you want a way to map your strings into a `TemperatureReading` instance:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream ;

public class TemperatureReadingParser {

    public TemperatureReading parse(String text) {
        return new TemperatureReading(
            Stream.of(text.split("\\s"))
            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
            .toArray());
    }
}
```

Now your code to keep reading looks like:

```
List<TemperatureReading> readings = new ArrayList<>();

TemperatureReadingParser parser = new TemperatureReadingParser();
double max = ... ;
Scanner input = ... ;
input.useDelimiter("\r\n");

TemperatureReading reading ;
do {
    reading = parser.parse(input.next());
    readings.add(reading);
} while (reading.noneExceed(max));

input.close();
```

Once you have the list of the readings, you can extract all values for a specific channel with

```
int channel = ... ;
double[] channelValues = readings.stream()
    .mapToDouble(reading -> reading.getValue(channel))
    .toArray();
```

and analyze them as you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give this a try. It does seem like making its own class would work well and I like the concept of having a specific class to handle each instance of readings.
I have a question about this line tho:
         System.arraycopy(values, 0, this.values, 0, values.length);
What are you doing here? why the 0s?

Comment: @DavidBoydston Did you read the [documentation for the method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)? (I'm copying the array to make the class immutable, if you were wondering why I was calling that method at all.)

Comment: Yes, I just read that I understand that now.
Also, what is the userDelimiter for? I dont understand that particular part of the code on how to keep reading.
I was thinking of using an event listener DATA_AVAILABLE.
Something like if there is data avialable and I have my logging boolean set to true it will log the data using that code you suggested, but I am not linking the input.userDelimiter, is it like a splitter?

Comment: @DavidBoydston Again, [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html): "A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern.... The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.". There is no need for an event listener for available data, the [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) method will block until data is available. The code does assume you will keep producing readings and that at some point a reading will be above the max.

Comment: See Edit on OP for response. Thank you so far and I'm sorry for the lack of reading of documentation, I'm still a beginner programmer but thank you sempai!

Comment: @DavidBoydston Not sure I understand the update to the OP. The `BufferedReader` seems redundant, and creating it will likely confuse the scanner (it might try to pre-fill the buffer from the input stream, for all we know: bottom line is you should never create two "higher-level" IO objects from the same "low level" one). If you want to mock this without the real data, you should probably create a specific class that exposes an input stream and pipes random or simulated data to it. This project seems a bit advanced for a beginner...

Comment: Yes, you are correct it's a bit complicated but I like challenging problems thats how I feel I end up learning the most.
Anyways, why I did that edit is because I fail to understand how the Scanner knows where to scan? I dont know if its implied somewhere in the class but from the documentation you have to tell the scanner what to scan (a string, a document or something) and your original code didnt set that at all or I didnt understand how it did, which is why I added that bufferreader since I know that actually outputs the readings from the device.

Comment: My code reads it from a `Scanner`. You can create a scanner from a file, or an input stream, or whatever you need...

Comment: Hi @James_D, I added your code to a modified version of an event listener, (see OP edit). this seems to work for a few moments but then I get error :
    SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes)
I know it's working for a few moments since the display code at the end (see OP works fine)

Comment: @DavidBoydston That is to do with your data source, and really has nothing to do with this question

Comment: Hi James_D, I am not sure about that, you see if I comment out these 3 lines I dont get any errors:
                    //TemperatureParser parser = new TemperatureParser();
                    //reading = parser.parse(reader.readLine());
                    //readings.add(reading);
so that's why I'm doubtful its the data source, or can you elaborate on what you mean by the data source?

Comment: @DavidBoydston "The error goes away if I don't try to read from the data source, therefore it can't be due to the data source." Really?

Comment: Well, no. If you look at the code I am still reading from the source, there are other lines that read. The appendtext line reads from the device and outputs the reading into a visible log. I will start a new discussion on this as you mentioned. I really appreciate all your help so far.